# symfony2 customize form select options

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to do a simple form to add an activity with a name and a color.

So I want to make a list with some an array of color, for now it is working I have the name of the color.
I can add any attribute to my select tag:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($myclass)
->add('Colors','choice',array('label'=>'select some colors',
            'multiple'=>true,
            'choices'=>array(1=>'red', 2=>'blue', 3=>'green'),
            'attr'=>array('style'=>'width:300px', 'customattr'=>'customdata')
            ));
```

The output will be something like this:

```
<select name="select" style="width: 300px;" multiple="multiple" customattr="customdata">
   <option value="1">red</option>
   <option value="2">blue</option>
   <option value="3">green</option>
</select>
```

But how can I add `selected="selected"` and any attribute I want to my select options ? like this:

```
<select name="select" style="width: 300px;" multiple="multiple" customattr="customdata">
   <option style="background-color: #F00;" value="1" selected="selected">red</option>
   <option style="background-color: #00F;" value="2" selected="selected">blue</option>
   <option style="background-color: #0F0;" value="3">green</option>
</select>
```

My question is: how can I add custom attr for `option` tag (not for `select` tag) by symfony FormBuilder.
**NOTICE:** I don't want to use JavaScript. I want to use symfony2 FormBuilder to customize my select options.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually, the default data of a field is determined by the value stored in your object. For example, if

```
class MyClass
{
    private $Colors = array(1, 2);
}
```

then the entries "1" and "2" (with the labels "red" and "green") will be displayed as selected by default. You could also store this value in the object before passing it to the form:

```
$myObject->Colors = array(1, 2);

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($myObject)
    ...
```

The last possibility is to override the default value stored in the object by passing the "data" option:

```
$builder->add('Colors', 'choice', array(
    'label' => 'select some colors',
    'multiple' => true,
    'choices' => array(1 => 'red', 2 => 'blue', 3 => 'green'),
    'attr' => array('style' => 'width:300px', 'customattr' => 'customdata'),
    'data' => array(1, 2),
));
```

Answer (score 3):

use the data option as described here fo selected="selected" :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/field.html

in ur case could be like this

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($myclass)
->add('Colors','choice',array('label'=>'select some colors',
            'multiple'=>true,
            'choices'=>array(1=>'red', 2=>'blue', 3=>'green'),
            'attr'=>array('style'=>'width:300px', 'customattr'=>'customdata'),
            'data'=> 1
            ));
```

the new element is **data** setting the number of the choice array as selected attribute

Answer (score 1):

Every `Field` in symfony inherits from [abstract field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/field.html), which has a `data` option, in which you can pass default option.

By the way, don't pass `style` stuff, and for custom attrs use [`data-*`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) attributes.

Comment: how can I use `data-` attributes? how I pass it to the FormBuilder. please explain more.

Comment: Just rename `customattr` to `data-customattr`, to be HTML-compliant.

Comment: I want to use `customattr` for my `option` tag, not for `select` tag. How can I do this by FormBuilder?

Comment: You didn't state this in the question - try overriding view [[some hints here](http://www.craftitonline.com/2012/07/symfony2-community-series-adding-variables-to-twig-output/)].

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Symfony 2.7 will add support to make this easier:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/14050

Answer (score 1):

Add in form class method Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType::finishView

```
public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    parent::finishView($view, $form, $options);

    $additionalAttributes = array();

    // myMethod - method $choice, returns a value that is to be substituted into the attribute
    foreach ($view->children['orders']->vars['choices'] as $id => $choice) {
        $additionalAttributes[$id] = array(
            'data-cost' => $this->propertyAccessor->getValue($choice->data, 'myMethod'),
            'disabled' => 'disabled',
        );
    }

    foreach ($view->children['orders']->children as $id => $child) {
        $child->vars['attr'] = array_replace(
            isset($child->vars['attr']) ? $child->vars['attr'] : array(),
            $additionalAttributes[$id]
        );
    }
}
```

[Symfony2 Form – add attribute tag option in select field type](http://zeka.kiev.ua/symfony2-form-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3-option-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%82/)

Answer (score 1):

In order to add your custom attribute on the choice, based on the value of that choice, consider using `choice_attr` option of the [ChoiceType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) field.

For example if you want to pass json encoded entity to the option, you can use something like this:

```
'choice_attr' => function($val, $key) {
   return ['data-object' => json_encode($val)];
},
```