# How to render each items of ChoiceType to add to them div and classes as I need

Tags: symfony

In past I render a form, but now I render each element of form in template.

How to render each items of  ChoiceType to add to them div and classes as I need.

I need to group all options in pairs wit two in one div `<div class="col-xs-2"> <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="styler" checked=""> 1</label> <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="styler"> 2</label> </div>` and also and also for all options.

I need to transform the Symfony 3 code (form elemetn of type ChoiceType) from :

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-2 text-right control-label">{% trans %}Example{% endtrans %}</label>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <label class="checkbox">{{ form_widget(form.examples, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control styler', 'checked': ''}}) }} Example</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To that form:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-2 text-right control-label">{% trans %}Example{% endtrans %}</label>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="styler" checked=""> 1</label>        
      <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="styler"> 2</label>        
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="styler"> 3</label> 
      <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="styler" checked=""> 4</label>       
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="styler" checked=""> 5</label> 
      <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="styler"> 6</label>       
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am new in Symfony. 
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have this form:

```
class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('inputName', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Choice',
            'choices' => [
                'Choice 1'=>'c1',
                'Choice 2'=>'c2',
                'Choice 3'=>'c3',
                'Choice 4'=>'c4',
                'Choice 5'=>'c5',
                'Choice 6'=>'c6',
            ]
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_form';
    }

}
```

Then you can access and group the choices from the form like this:

```
{{ form_widget(form) }}

{% set groupSize = 2 %}
{% set auxGroup = 0 %}
<div>
    {% for choice in form.inputName.vars.choices %}
        {{ dump(choice) }}
        {% set auxGroup = auxGroup + 1 %}
        {% if auxGroup == groupSize %}
            </div><div>
            {% set auxGroup = 0 %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I didn't add the classes, labels and other front end stuff as it's not relevant.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217431/symfony2-customize-form-select-options

Comment: Try `form.inputName.vars.choices` Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497133/directly-access-a-form-fields-value-when-overriding-widget-in-a-twig-template
Basically if you'll dump the `form` object you'll find the array of your input choices and you can foreach it

Comment: Can you please check the answer once again. I tried it on the Symfony 3, it worked. I edited it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151075/discussion-between-keloo-and-michael).

Answer (score 0):

I see that the post is from a long time ago but I was expose to the same issue.

I first try to solve the issue with PHP in the FromType but after several failure I solve it in JS.

You just need to call createDivWithFromFieldClassForEachPairOfInputAndLabel() with a NodeList of input in argument and adapte with your CSS the name of the class in he setAttribute() method.

```
createDivWithFromFieldClassForEachPairOfInputAndLabel: function (inputs) {
console.log("createDivWithFromFieldClassForEachPairOfInputAndLabel()");

// We create a array of formFields.
let formFields = [];

// For each input of inputs.
for (input of inputs) {
  // We create a HTML element with the tag name div.
  let formField = document.createElement("div");
  // We set a class and and a class name on the created element.
  formField.setAttribute("class", "form-field");
  // We insert a formField before each input.
  input.insertAdjacentElement("beforebegin", formField);
  // We push each formField to formFields.
  formFields.push(formField);
}

// For each field of formFields.
for (field of formFields) {
  // We get each input which are the nextElementSibling of each field.
  let input = field.nextElementSibling;
  // We get each label which are the nextElementSibling each field.
  let label = input.nextElementSibling;
  // We add each input in each field.
  field.appendChild(input);
  // We add each label in each field.
  field.appendChild(label);
}
```

},